# in TensorFlow runtime, how tensors are copied?

Tags: tensorflow

I am reading the whole Tensorflow source code, and has been puzzled by one thing. In an Op, we can get the underlying data buffer of an input tensor and change its value, but this change will not reflected outside this op (the input is not a Ref type).

For example, 
       y = op1(x)
       z = op2(x)
in op1, suppose we get the underlying buffer of x and change its value, but when I run y_val, z_val = sess.run([y, z]), it seems that this does not affect the value of z (it x really changes, z should change).

here since x tensor is consumed by two ops, I initially think maybe tensorflow split x into two tensors, one as the input of op1, and the other as input of op2. However, I checked the code, it seems not.

Another possibility is that tensor is copy-on-write, but it also seems not after I checked the code.

Anyone know what really happen here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry i dint get your question can you provide the complete code what you have tried.

Comment: Why not just make `x` a variable? Allowing ops to mutate their *inputs* would mean this is no longer [dataflow programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), which messes everything up (one example: execution order would change output).

Comment: @AllenLavoie Thanks for answering. I understand that if x is a variable, the change will be reflected outside. However, if x is not passed as Ref, but I changed the content of its underlying buffer, why this does not reflect outside?  I thought maybe because there is copy operation of tensor, but cannot find them in the source code.

Comment: Let us see one example, suppose x is an tensor, and we have: 
     y = op1(x)
     z = op2(x)
Suppose in op1, I get the underlying buffer of x, and changed its content,
why this does not affect z? 
In my opinion, there are multiple ways to achieve this:
1) when a tensor is passed into an Op, do a copy.  This will be very expensive;
2) When a tensor will be passed into multiple Ops, copy the tensor except for input of the first Op;
3) The tensor is copy-on-write;
However, I did not find any of these in source code. I am trying to figure out how Tensorflow deal with this situation

Comment: Tensor objects do [share buffers with each other](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fa8bb43b12478a7b0d9e36e6bbf8ba4f490c961c/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc#L498). Not sure what you're trying, so it's hard to say why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks again. I mean, for the consideration of memory saving and efficiency, Tensor objects share buffers as much as possible. But in some case, such as a tensor x is the input of two Ops, such as Op1 and Op2, how x is shared?  The first possibility is that x is shared by these two Ops. In this case, if I change the content of the underlying buffer of x, it should be reflected in in another Ops. I did some experiments, this seems to be untrue. Another possibilities are 1) x is passed to Op1, and a deep copy is passed to Op2, or 2) x is copy-on-write. But I cannot find them in the source code